# How could you get the average of all contour coordinates and display it as a point in openCV?

Tags: python, opencv, contour

```
cv2.erode(binary_img, M, iterations=100)
edges = cv2.Canny(binary_img, 128, 256)

contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for cnt in contours : 

  approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.009 * cv2.arcLength(cnt, True), True) 

  # draws boundary of contours. 
  cv2.drawContours(output_img, [approx], 0, (0, 0, 255), 5) 

  # Used to flatted the array containing 
  # the co-ordinates of the vertices. 
  n = approx.ravel() 
  i = 0

  for j in n : 
     if(i % 2 == 0): 
        x = n[i] 
        y = n[i + 1] 

     i = i + 1
```

I can get the x and y coordinate for each contour but I'm unsure of how to find the average of all of them and turn it into a point.

Comment: do you mean `sum(all_x)/len(all_x)`? you would have to add values `x += ... `, `y += ... ` and later `x/i` and `y/i`

Answer (score 0):

If you mean `sum(all_x)/len(all_x)` then you could add values `x += ...` , `y += ...` and `count` points (or get `count = len(n)/2`) and later get `x/count` and `y/count`

```
  count = 0
  sum_x = 0
  sum_y = 0

  for j in n : 
     if i % 2 == 0: 
        sum_x += n[i] 
        sum_y += n[i + 1] 
        count += 1

  avg_x = sum_x / count
  avg_y = sum_y / count
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused because when using drawContours using avg_x and avg_y as the contour is gives (-215 assertion failure) npoint > 0

Comment: `avg_x, avg_y` gives single point so it can't draw contours. As for me contour may need 3 points to create at least triangle. Maybe you should draw circle with center in `avg_x, avg_y`, Or rectangle `avg_x, avg_y, avg_x+1, avg_y+1`. Besides `contour` would need values in special structure - probably 2D list - check what you have in `approx` before you flatten it.